# WireMock stubbing code in Java and using a variable for WireMockServer object

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, wiremock

Started using WireMock and managed to write the first working code parts to mock rest calls using HttpURLConnection.

I did struggle in the beginning and was getting the error `connection refused` when executing the `stubFor()` method. I am running the code below in JUnit 4 class, and not using JUnit Rule to initialize the WireMockServer:

```
public class TestHttpURLConnectionMock {
    private final static int WIREMOCK_PORT = 8089;
    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:" + WIREMOCK_PORT + "/";
    private final static String JWT_RESPONSE_JSON;
    static {
        JWT_RESPONSE_JSON = "{\r\n" 
                + ...
                + "}";
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.out.println("This is the Setup Method");
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(WIREMOCK_PORT));
        wireMockServer.start();
        loggerWrapper.debug(CAT_NAME, "WireMock server started.");
    }

    @Test
    public void _01_testCallHttpURLConnection() throws Exception {
        wireMockServer.stubFor(
            post(urlEqualTo("/" + AUTH_PART_URL))
            .willReturn(
                ok()
                .withBody(JWT_RESPONSE_JSON)
            )
        );
        MyService myService = new MyService(false); //This is a wrapper over HttpURLConnection
        myService.setEndPointBaseURL(BASE_URL);
        myService.setAuthPartURL(AUTH_PART_URL);
        myService.setSslFlag(SSL_FALSE);
        myService.setClient_id(USER_ID);
        myService.setClient_secret(USER_SECRET);
        try {
            myService.callWSAuth();
            final int EXPECT_EXPIRES = 3600;
            JWTResponse resp=null;
            resp = myService.getJWTResponse();
            collector.checkThat(resp.getHttpResponseCode(), is(myService.getHttpURLCon().getResponseCode()));
            if (myService.getHttpURLCon().getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                collector.checkThat(resp, notNullValue());
                collector.checkThat(resp.getAccess_token(), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
                collector.checkThat(resp.getExpires_in(), is(EXPECT_EXPIRES));
                System.out.println("JWT from response: " + resp.getAccess_token());
            }
            collector.checkThat(resp.getError(), isEmptyOrNullString());
            collector.checkThat(resp.getHttpResponseCode(), is(HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK));
            collector.checkThat(resp.getResponseAsJson(), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
            System.out.println("JWT Response as Json =\n" + resp.getResponseAsJson());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            fail(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

The above code is working fine, and I have the following questions:

1. If I don't specify the variable `wireMockServer` with the method `stubFor()` I will get a connection refused error. This is not mentioned anywhere in the WireMock documentation pages. All the provided sample code uses the method `stubFor()` directly. I had to call the method as follows `wireMockServer.stubFor()`. Please help me understand this part.
2. If I don't specify the `/` at ate beginning of the url for `urlEqualTo("/" + AUTH_PART_URL)`. This was not clear to me also. I thought it should work without spespecifying` in the beginning.

I appreciate your help.